# authentification doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm trying to make an authentication form with PHP and MySQL but it doesn't work and I'm wondering why.

Is there anybody who can help me ? I did a password hash in a precedent file, but they are not linked. This one is independant .

Thank you !

```
<?php

session_start();

function connect_db($host, $port, $db, $username, $password)
{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; port=$port; dbname=$db", $username, $password);
    return $pdo;
}

if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST["password"]))
{
    $error_pass= "";
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    try
    {
        $pdo = connect_db("localhost", 3306, "*******", "******", "*******");
        $sql = $pdo-> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password");
        $sql->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $sql->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $sql->execute();
        $req = $sql->fetch();
        echo $req["password"] . "SALUT \n";
        var_dump($req["password"]);
        if (password_verify($password, $req['password']) == 0) {
            session_unset();
            $error_pass = "Incorrect email/password";
        }

        else {
            $_SESSION["name"] = $req["name"];
            header("Location: index.php", true, 302);
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    if ($error_pass) {
        echo $error_pass;
    }
}

else {
    echo "Some fields are missing";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action ="login.php">
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <input type="text" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value ="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: bindParam needs to be with :,so `$sql->bindParam(':email', $email);`

Comment: Yes sorry it's a mistake but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Safety tip: you should try to avoid posting your usernames + passwords on the internet. Also, make that password stronger if that's the one you plan on using in production.

Comment: "doesn't work" Well thats not very dewscriptive

Answer (score 2):

Remove password from your query. You need to find user only by email and then verify that password is correct.

```
$sql = $pdo-> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
$sql->bindParam(':email', $email);
$sql->execute();
$req = $sql->fetch();

// @todo :: check did you got any users

if (password_verify($_POST["password"], $req['password'])) {
    // password is valid
}
```

Comment: Yup. The password in the database is hashed, so the unhashed version will never equal the hashed version, so `$sql->fetch();` will return 0 rows.